# How to set multiple state values from input in react class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have some state values which i want to set after the submit button is pressed according to what user types in the form and change the state accordingly. i have a handleChange function which is supposed to fill the state variables with the input values and a onSubmitTask function which for now just logs the state. I also get a warning from the log

Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
at input
at div
at form
at div
at App

after i first access the iput.

```
// import GeneralInfo from "./components/GeneralInfo";

class App extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      general: {
        fname: "",
        lname: "",
        email: "",
        phn: "",
        location: ""
      }
    }
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      general: {
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
      }
    });
  }

  onSubmitTask = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {

    const { general } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form action="#" onSubmit={this.onSubmitTask}> 
          <div id="name">
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={general.fname}/>
            <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={general.lname}/>
          </div>
          <div id="rest">
            <input type="text" id="phn" placeholder="ph number" onChange={this.handleChange} value={general.phn}/>
            <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="email@example.com" onChange={this.handleChange} value={general.email}/>
            <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="city, state" onChange={this.handleChange} value={general.location}/>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

this is the code that i have been trying.

````
    this.setState({
      general: {
        [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
      }
    });```
I saw this function online but i dont really know what it does but it doesnt work also. do i have to create seperate functions that change the individual state and call the onChange from there or is there a better method of doing this?

most the answers on the internet uses hooks, i want to do this using class components and not hooks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Okay got this. just had to enumerate the general state so that the state values can be set properly

````
    this.setState({
      general: {
        ...this.state.general,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      }
    });
  }```
````